# Parse string with minus sign, retain minus sign

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
latlonginput = 'Latitude=28.0358214, Longitude=-82.59970229999999, Accuracy=4232m'

import re

try:
    #latlonginput = input['latlong']
    geo_lat = format(re.split(r'(Latitude=|,)', latlonginput)[2])
    geo_long = format(re.split(r'(Longitude=|,)', latlonginput)[2])
    accuracy = format(re.split(r'(Accuracy=)', latlonginput)[2])
    geo_coord = geo_lat + ',' + geo_long
    latlong = 'Detected Lat/Long: '+ geo_coord + '\n'
    latlong = latlong + 'Accuracy: ' + accuracy + '\n'
    latlong = latlong + 'Maps: placeholder'
except:
    latlong = None

return {'lat_long': latlong }
```

In this case, with longitude being a negative value, it omits the negative. For example, this is the result:

```
Detected Lat/Long: 28.0358214,
Accuracy: 4232m
Maps: placeholder
```

I need to allow for negatives in either latitude or longitude. How can I adjust to do so?

Thanks,
Noob

Comment: `geo_lat = format(re.split(r'(Latitude=|,)', latlonginput)[2])` this does too much in one line of code. Use variables generously to store intermediate results. This will allow you to inspect the values of these variables with a debugger or `print()` statements. For more debugging tips, read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expressions are overkill for this; just split the string on `", "` first, then split each element on `"="`:

```
>>> dict(x.split('=') for x in latlonginput.split(', '))
{'Latitude': '28.0358214', 'Longitude': '-82.59970229999999', 'Accuracy': '4232m'}
```

Then use the dictionary as necessary.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a regular expression with optional matching to check for negative signs in front of your desired numbers.

Also if this is your format of your strings, using `re.split` is not needed, you can simply match.

If those numbers are the only numbers present in your string, you can simply use:

```
In [11]: re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d+m?', s)
Out[11]: ['28.0358214', '-82.59970229999999', '4232m']
```

If you want to make this more robust, you could match that entire format:

```
import re

rgx = r'Latitude=(-?\d+\.\d+).*Longitude=(-?\d+\.\d+).*Accuracy=-?(\d+m)'
s = 'Latitude=28.0358214, Longitude=-82.59970229999999, Accuracy=4232m'

lat, long, accuracy = re.findall(rgx, s)[0]
print('Lat/Long: {}, {}\nAccuracy: {}'.format(lat, long, accuracy))
```

Output:

```
Lat/Long: 28.0358214, -82.59970229999999
Accuracy: 4232m
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change second line to **(index of 4 instead of 2)**

```
geo_long = format(re.split(r'(Longitude=|,)', latlonginput)[4])
```

I prefer @chepner's answer to save processing time.

#### Output

```
Detected Lat/Long: 28.0358214,-82.59970229999999
Accuracy: 4232m
Maps: placeholder
```